# How to get the Values from the Entry box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def in_Vals():
    in_win = Tk()
    in_win.title("Check In Details")
    in_win.geometry("700x700")
    in_win.resizable(0,0)

    # title

    title = Label(in_win,text="Check In Details",font=("Harlow Solid Italic",30,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    title.pack(anchor="center",pady=5)

    #creating label's
    _Id_ = Label(in_win,text="Id :",font=("Times New Roman",15,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    _Name_ = Label(in_win,text="Name :",font=("Times New Roman",15,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    _Date_ = Label(in_win,text="Date :",font=("Times New Roman",15,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    _Time_ = Label(in_win,text="Time :",font=("Times New Roman",15,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    _Number_ = Label(in_win,text="Number :",font=("Times New Roman",15,"italic"),fg="black",bg="#fbb08c")
    
    
    _Id_.pack(anchor='w',padx=10,pady=20)
    _Name_.pack(anchor='w',padx=10,pady=20)
    _Date_.pack(anchor='w',padx=10,pady=20)
    _Time_.pack(anchor='w',padx=10,pady=20)
    _Number_.pack(anchor='w',padx=10,pady=20)

    # creating submit function

    def submit():
        print(f"{in_val_1}\n{in_val_2}\n{in_val_3}\n{in_val_4}\n{in_val_5}")


    # creating entries

    Id = Entry(in_win,width=25,font=("Courier",15,'bold'))
    Name = Entry(in_win,width=25,font=("Courier",15,'bold'))
    Date = Entry(in_win,width=25,font=("Courier",15,'bold'))
    Time = Entry(in_win,width=25,font=("Courier",15,'bold'))
    Number = Entry(in_win,width=25,font=("Courier",15,'bold'))

    Id.place(x=100,y=87)
    Name.place(x=100,y=157)
    Date.place(x=100,y=227)
    Time.place(x=100,y=293)
    Number.place(x=100,y=360)

    #getting values

    in_val_1 = Id.get()
    in_val_2 = Name.get()
    in_val_3 = Date.get()
    in_val_4 = Time.get()
    in_val_5 = Number.get()


    # creating submit button

    submit = Button(in_win,text="Submit",font=("Wild Latin",15,"bold"),command=submit)
    submit.place(x = 250,y=450)
    
    in_win.config(bg="#fbb08c")
    in_win.mainloop()
```

Here the function **in_vals()** is a coded to take data from the ID, Name, Date, Time, Number Entries and assign the values of The entries to the variables **in_val_1 to in_val_5** ,to get the values from the entry box I have used the **.get()**  Method. but when I try to Print the Variables that I assigned to the **.get()** method, it prints some white Space's.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859791/my-tkinter-button-works-but-isnt-running-its-relevant-command/71860067#71860067) answer. Both questions involve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the Values from the Entry box in Tkinter?

Never do in swapping.  Comment out line 49 to 53.

```
#in_val_1 = Id.get()
#in_val_2 = Name.get()
#in_val_3 = Date.get()
#in_val_4 = Time.get()
#n_val_5 = Number.get()
```

Change this in line 30 in `submit()` function :

```
print(f"{in_val_1}\n{in_val_2}\n{in_val_3}\n{in_val_4}\n{in_val_5}")
```

to:

```
print(f"{Id.get()}\n{Name.get()}\n{Date.get()}\n{Time.get()}\n{Number.get()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem same as mine is

defining the values outside the the button function does not get anything.

here I have defined out side the button function

after defining it inside the button function it gives me the desired output